# Where to store large number of JSON files

Tags: json, database, nosql

We are in the process of setting up a web application (start up at present). The web application will quickly grow in terms of number of JSON files that it needs to handle. We are probably talking about 5-10 million files. The individual JSON files are not particularly large - maybe in the region of 150K per file. Files will unlikely be accessed concurrently so individual users have their set of individual files.

The question I would like to put out there is simply how to best store the JSON files. Is a CDN best where links are stored in a relational database? Or should I jump on the bandwagon and go down the route of a NoSQL database? Or maybe there are other solutions I haven't thought about???

really looking for some good advice, ideally from someone with experience about large databases.

Many thanks in advance!!!!

Markus

Answer (score 0):

I would consider looking into MongoDB since it already stores its documents in a json format. 
You could also stick it into a regular relational db, but the nice thing about working with json documents in mongo is that you will have query capabilities against the documents, so that you don't have to load the entire document always.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. What if I don't need to query the files (ever). They are simply used as content delivery to the web app user.

Comment: I guess you can make it work with all suggested solutions, but I would probably consider that it might be a maintenance issue to deploy your application with such a large number of files.

Comment: The maintenance was/is one of our major concerns as well. Thanks again for your comment!

Answer (score 0):

If all you want is quick access to a write-once-read-many type of storage, then you can also consider DBM. It is fast, cheap, reliable.

Assuming you will compress the file contents, JSON-ness is probably a nonfactor from storage perspective.

Reliability - can you tolerate some statistical loss? If not, an all-or-bust DBs is the only choice left. If not, filesystem-based storage may be an alternative. Filesystems are not as fanatical as DB on whole data integrity checks. And they are much better supported. Serving files is easier; but keeping track of versions takes more design time effort. A common enough pattern is to serve product images and other collateral out of filesystem while keeping other data in an rdbms.

If you consider CDN -> relational DB then could also consider CDN -> {filesystem, inode}, keeping filesystems balanced explicitly in terms of file count.

NoSQL database, like MongoDB, might have restart and recovery times beyond your tolerance levels. Otherwise it's great tool. Many RDBMS have raw partition support for much better IO. At 150KB one must use a TEXT or CLOB field, just a minor annoyance.

HTH. Will appreciate if you shared back what you actually used.

Comment: Thanks for the input. We are currently playing around with it. One solution might be to go for both (CDN and RDBMS for the free part of the tool) and NoSQL for the paying customers. hard to know how things turn out once large numbers are emerging. I will report back once it is up and running with more concrete bits of information and other measures of interest! Thanks again!!